# SSH Passphrase Dialog Drops to Terminal Passphrase Entry when Canceled

Tags: ssh, centos7, sshfs, passphrase

We're using sshfs to mount a remote directory for a UI program. To kick things off, we launch a system process to set up the mount using sshfs terminal commands. This works well: a dialog pops up asking the user for their passphrase, the mount is created, and all is well.

However, the program is hanging if the user selects "Cancel" in the dialog. Doing this operation through the terminal reveals that when the user cancels the dialog, ssh(fs) drops back to the terminal and prompts for a passphrase entry there. This is invisible to our system call, of course, which is why things hang.

How can I tell ssh(fs) that cancel means cancel? When the UI dialog goes away, I want the command line to simply return.